# vertically center align text in the UIlabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want the text written in the UILabel to be aligned center vertically.

How can I do that? My label's name is phoneLabel. Here I am attaching an image:

[image]

See the phone number, the label is completely aligned with the whatsapp image but the text does not look good as it is not aligned vertically centered.

Here are the contraints:

[image]

Comment: show your constraints

Comment: You have to give the same height to both WhatsApp ImageView/Button and label of Phone Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is here you added top space = 6 for UILabel remove it. Add center vertical
>   constraints to image.

Additionally if you have setted leading & trailing then no need of width constraints.

Make sure below things

1. Set constraints to phoneLabel which is center vertically to your
   whatsapp image.
2. Set your UILabel content/text alignment to be Center.
3. **Remove top & bottom spacing of UILabel**. Only these constraints
   enough  height,center vertical to image,leading & trailing spaces.

Comment: Glad to help i can see answer is accepted.So problem solved?? You can upvote too

Comment: You can additionally set a height constraint to DS Dharma suggestion or Equal Heights for the Image and Label so what ever the image size is the label height will that that area. Also There is a Vertically center constraint in the autolayout set so all align to middle for each other the three icons and your label. this will given you perfect alignments.